# почему python долго работает?

Tags: python

ну почему он так долго всё делает? ну зачем он такой??

Comment: Почему вы решили, что проблема в python, а не в ваших непродуманных алгоритмах?

Comment: Может у вас программа просто зациклилась? :-)

Comment: Покажите пример, который заставил вас задать данный вопрос.

Comment: Возьмите Питоновский компилятор, а не интерпретатор. Код после компилятора будет немногим медленнее, чем код после компилятора С/С++.

Answer (score 7):

Возможно, проблема заключается в выборе языка программирования для ваших задач. Не все задачи одинаково хорошо решаются одним и тем же инструментом. Например, гвоздь можно забить как молотком, так и топором. Но, используя последний инструмент, вы можете нанести вред себе, гвоздю или окружению. Поэтому я рекомендую сначала определиться с выбором решения вашей задачи, потом с выбором целевой платформы и, соответственно, языка программирования.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема может заключаться в следующем:

- ЭВМ на которой осуществляется попытка запуска python-инструкции для обработки не удовлетворяет системным требованиям транслятора python
- Написанные вами python-инструкции недостаточно оптимизированы для работы на конечной ЭВМ
- Написанные вами python-инструкции не являются корректными
- Язык python является плохим выбором для осуществления нужных вам действии

Answer (score 3):

Проблема может заключается в следующем:
1)У вас старый ПК и он не тянет python(такое тоже может быть)
2)У вас не верно написан код или онне оптимизирован,как говорят "грязный"(т.е слишком много ненужных вещей),из за чего компьютер нагружается и он долго работает.

Comment: Это, конечно, субъективное мнение, но на StackOverflow я ожидал увидеть более подробный ответ... Может, Вы детализируете его?